# Mysql Count distinct users in a table

Tags: mysql, sql

I need to group by date the records in the log table, and for that specific day the number of accesses by a regualar employee or specialEmployee. The accesses should be distinct for example if a type of user logged in twice, it should only be counted once for that day

```
Type
PK typeId
name

Employee
PK empId
firstName
lastName
FK typeId     


Log
PK logId
FK empId
date
```

I've tried the query below, but to no avail. When I replace the sum/case with count it works but then I can't specify which type of user to count distinctly

```
SELECT L.`date`
SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN E.typeId =1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as specialEmployeeAccesses,
SUM(DISTINCT CASE WHEN E.typeId=2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as regularEmployeeAccesses
FROM LOG L
INNER JOIN
Employee E
ON E.empId = L.empId
GROUP BY L.`date`
```

Comment: **Remove** the `Distinct`

Comment: But I need to count users who accessed the system for that day only once. So if a special user logged in three times, it should count as one, that is why I tried distinct. If i remove it what should I do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT L.`date`,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN E.typeId=1 THEN E.empId END) 
            as specialEmployeeAccesses,
       COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN E.typeId=2 THEN E.empId END) 
            as regularEmployeeAccesses
FROM LOG L
INNER JOIN Employee E
ON E.empId = L.empId
GROUP BY L.`date`
```